# Meteor signups are forbidden

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I've been hunting around, and I've seen similar posts, which were all fixed by removing a package, or adding `forbidClientAccountCreation: false;`I am using accounts-password, and accounts-ui, I've included the `{{> loginbuttons}}` But I still can't create users. From the documentation, it's supposed to simply work, without writing any further code... As do many tutorials I looked at... Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean you can't self-register? This setting is usually in a startup method in a a `/common` or `/both` folder.

This file is from one of my projects as `/both/startup.js`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
//
// This code is run by both client and server. For Accounts.config this is a MUST!
//
Meteor.startup(() => {

  Accounts.config({
    sendVerificationEmail: false,
    forbidClientAccountCreation: true
  });

});
```

Comment: As I indicated in my post, I've already added that to my project, and signups are still forbidden

Comment: Can you do a search through the project for forbidClientAccountCreation ?

Comment: The only instance is where I've added it in my imports/shared/shared.js
Toggling the value here adds/removes the link to create an account, but I still get the forbidden error

Comment: Are you getting a 'forbidden' error? If so, that is something else